# Where and how can I download Adobe CS 5.5 and buy its licence?

Tags: download, license, adobe-cs5

Where and how can I download Adobe CS 5.5 and its licence? I can't seem to find it anymore? They only option Adobe forces on me is CS 6.

Comment: Do you even have a license for CS 5.5?  If you don't then you won't be able to install it.

Comment: Yeah, several, but all used. We need CS 5.5 download and key.

Comment: If all your licenses are used then you won't be able to install it.  Online stores like Amazon have it in stock and for sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to contact Adobe directly. If you already have a license for CS5.5 they should be able to provide you with installation media.

If on the other hand you are wanting to buy CS5.5, then you may well be out of luck, as i think they are only selling 6 and above (creative cloud) now.